# Do function type parameter labels matter

Tags: f#

I'm teaching myself F#.  My question comes from my attempts to solve exercise 2.13 in the book 'Functional Programming Using F#', which asks me to define a function curry as:

```
curry : ('a * 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

My current result is

```
curry : f:('a * b' -> 'c) -> x:'a -> y:'b -> 'c
```

**Question**
Do the parameter labels matter?  Is my solution correct, or does the correct solution not have the labels f:, x: , and y:?

Comment: I would call your solution correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a functional perspective (as-in, how it works, not as-in functional programming), the thing that matters is whether or not they are equivalent.  The way to test this is to see if the two are interchangeable.

Lets pretend you defined your function like this (notice the type signature matches yours):

```
let curry f x y =
    f(x,y);;

val curry : f:('a * 'b -> 'c) -> x:'a -> y:'b -> 'c
```

Then, lets define a second function which takes a function of the desired type signature like this:

```
let makeCurried (f: ('a * 'b -> 'c)->'a->'b->'c) g : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) = f g;;

val makeCurried :
  f:(('a * 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c) ->
    g:('a * 'b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c)
```

Notice that the first parameter of `makeCurried` takes a function of type `('a * 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c`.

Now the test is: can you pass the `curry` function to `makeCurried` for the first parameter?  If so, then the two are equivalent.

```
makeCurried curry (fun (x,y)->x*y);;

val it : (int -> int -> int) = <fun:it@7>
```

Yes! So the annotations on the type signature don't matter since the type signatures are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

No, the parameter labels don't matter for the solution to this exercise, which is why they were left out of the expected solution. A function defined as `let curry f x y = ...` and a function defined as `let curry funcToCurry firstParam secondParam = ...` would both be valid solutions, as long as they did the right thing. What matters in this exercise is the *shape* of the resulting function (that is, the types that it takes and returns), not the names you gave its parameter(s).